# Jasmine spy and resolving promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am testing a controller that uses a service that returns a promise.  I have mocked out a service in my tests and created a `spy` so that I can test if the service was actually called.

However I keep getting this error

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function 
    (evaluating 'spyOn(mockService, 'one').andReturn(deferred.promise)')
```

My Test

```
beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, $q) {
  scope = $rootScope.$new();

  mockService = {
    one: function(){
      // mock promise
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      deferred.resolve([
        //my array
      ]);
      return deferred.promise;
    },
    two: function(){
      // mock promise
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      deferred.resolve([
        //my data
      ]);
      return deferred.promise;
    }
  }
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  spyOn(mockService, 'one').andReturn(deferred.promise);

  controller = $controller('MyCtrl', {
    $scope: scope,
    mockService: mockService
  });
}));

it('should call mockService service', function(){
  //causes promises to check to see if they are fulfilled
  scope.$digest();
  expect(mockService.one).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: which version of jasmine are you using?

Comment: correction: version 2.4.1 of jasmine

Answer (score 1):

For Jasmine 2 you must use

```
spyOn(mockService, 'one').and.returnValue(deferred.promise);
```

instead of `andReturn()`.

[Read the docs](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies:_<code>and.returnValue</code>). If you're migrating from Jasmine 1 to Jasmine 2, you also might want to [read this](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/upgrading.html).